# ¿Como cambiar el tamaño de un JPanel que esta dentro de un JFrame?

Tags: java, poo, jframe, ventana, jpanel

Tengo un JPanel dentro de un JFrame, cuando quiero darle un tamaño especifico al JPanel con el método `setBounds()` el JPanel se adapta al tamaño que tiene el JFrame ignorando lo establecido en el `setBounds()`, ¿Como puedo solucionarlo ?

Este es mi código:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JTableDisplay extends JFrame{
    
    JPanel panel;
    

    public JTableDisplay() {
        setSize(500,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 50);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

     
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTableDisplay jt=new JTableDisplay();
        jt.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public JTableDisplay() {
        setSize(500,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
        setLayout(null);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 50);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        add(panel);
        
    }
```

Por defecto los JFrame incluyen el `BorderLayout()`, para poder ajustar y cambiar los tamaños de los componentes que tendrá el JFrame es necesario indicar `null` en el método `setLayout()` con eso el JFrame no estaría manejando ningún tipo de Layout.